# "undefined is not a function" grunt less

Tags: css, gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-less

Good afternoon , trying to deal with the assembly , but get the error:

"undefined is not a function"

My folder structure:
-/less
  style.less
 --/components
  header.less
-/css
-/img
-/js

I installed : grunt-contrib-less
and that my file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    less: {
        development: {
            options: {
                paths: ["less"]
            },
            files: {
                "css/style.css": "less/style.less"
            }
        }
    },
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.registerTasks('default',['less']);
};
```

in style.less I wrote: @import "components/page-header.less";

tell me what my mistake?

Comment: In which line of your code is the error thrown?

Comment: when I run grunt, Loading Gruntfile.js tasks error

Comment: And it won't tell you at which line of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Last line should be (no trailing `s` for `registerTask`):

`grunt.registerTask('default',['less']);`